# How visualize a Volume

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, visualization

I need to calculate some volumes, but I can't because I'm not able to visualize them.I 'm not able to set the integrals. I'm going to show my problem:

I have that volume $V:=\{\ \underline{x} \in \mathbb{R^3} : x,y,z \ge 0 ,\ z \le 2-x^2-y,\ z \le x+2y \} \\ \underline{x}:=(x,y,z)$

How can I see it? Should I only use algebra and abandon any visual approach? If yes how? Thanks in advance

P.S.
Obviously the tools like Geogebra 3D I don't take them into consideration, I would like to succeed in this without using these tools.

I would also like to add that generally if I can see the volume I have no problems with the integral calculation. The problem is all there, sometimes I can see the volume at other times absolutely not!

Comment: Can you visualize the surfaces $z = 2-x^2 - y$ and $z= x+2y$ (with equality)?

Comment: The linear surface should be easy to visualize, for the quadratic check: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticSurface.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric there are only so many different types (I think only 3 types) of those surfaces so you can identify which quadratic surface it is and already have a picture in mind of what it is. Wikipedia has a nice list there with visualization, verify a few of those and I believe this will already help you to see how this works in a general case.

Comment: $z=x+2y$ yes, but the first absolutely not!

Comment: Try searching $2-x^2-y$ on Google and set bounds of $0 < x < 10$ and $0 < y < 10$. The 2D cross-section looks like $2-x^2$ as $-x^2$ dominates, but it slopes down as $y$ increases due to the $-y$ term.

Comment: @TobyMak I don't want to use google, I'll never learn if I delegate work to others

Comment: It would be better to see computers as aids: they can be useful to gain intuition and help us start a problem, but most of the work still comes from us. It's not like the computer is plotting the exact volume right? I'm sure you can use the computer as a positive step to help you find all the boundaries and compute the integral. *Sometimes, it's okay to need a bit of help.*

Comment: @TobyMak No, but I'm definitely not saying that I don't want to use the computer. I badly explained myself. What I'm saying is that if I use a computer I can calculate the volume right away, but it's of no use because if I were to find myself without the computer that displays the graphic I would be unable to do it!

Comment: @them I am seeing but there is no case for my equation. In case you find it in practice, should I remember the graphic equivalent for each equation by heart?

Comment: So when would you find yourself without a computer? During a test?

Comment: For this case, you could visualise what happens as $x$ increases, and what happens when $y$ increases. Notice for your domain that $x^2$ and $y$ are all positive, so the absolute maximum is $2$ for $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @TobyMak Yes for example. But in general I would not be able to draw it myself

Comment: @ABC I think there is something very close to your case (in both links), look at Parabolic cylinder.

Comment: In general, do you recommend a purely algebraic approach or is it impossible?

Comment: @them I have graphed $-x^2-y-z = 0$ I would not be able to deduce it knowing only $-x^2-y = 0$

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume throughout much of this that you're comfortable with at least double integrals and related iterated integrals.

First I discuss how to visualize the region enough to set up the integrals, focusing primarily on understanding the "shadow" in the $xy$-plane. Then, after a second horizontal line, I also show a wordy algebra-only calculation to set up the integrals.

---

## How to visualize a volume:

### Boundary Surfaces (skippable):

We might like to visualize the boundary surfaces $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$, $z=2-x^{2}-y$ and $z=x+2y$. It will turn out that visualizing these 3D graphs is not really needed for a problem like this.

The first three, $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$, are just the coordinate planes.

$z=x+2y$ is a plane (because it's a degree $1$ equation) that passes through the origin with cross-sections that have slope $1$ in the $x$ direction (for fixed $y$) and $2$ in the $y$ direction (for fixed $x$). (It's also the case that $\left\langle 1,2,-1\right\rangle$  is perpendicular to the plane, but I don't find that as helpful for this sort of visualization.)

It remains to understand $z=2-x^{2}-y$. There are a lot of options, but I still like cross-sections here. For each fixed $y$, we have a parabola. For example, $y=0$ gives the downward parabola $z=2-x^{2}$. $y=1$ gives the downward parabola $1-x^{2}$. And $y=2$ gives the downward parabola $z=-x^{2}$, which never has $z$ positive. This already tells us that all of the points of the volume satisfy $0\le y\le2$, as $y>2$ would mean $0\le z\le2-x^{2}-y\le2-y<0$. For each fixed $x$, we have a line. For example, $x=0$ gives $z=2-y$. $x=1$ gives $z=1-y$. And $x=\sqrt{2}$ gives $z=-y$, which never has $z$ positive for $y\ge0$. So all points of the volume satisfy $0\le x\le\sqrt{2}$.

### Intersections:

Whether or not we understand the boundary surfaces, we need to understand where they intersect within the volume.

#### Intersections of Surfaces:

As long as we keep in mind that we're in the first quadrant where $x,y\ge0$, we don't have to consciously worry about the intersections with $x=0$ and $y=0$ right now, since the rest of our conditions are given in terms of $z$, which means we're likely to set up a double integral with respect to $x$ and $y$.

Let's start with $z=0$. $z=x+2y$ intersects $z=0$ when $x+2y=0$ so that $y=-x/2$. But since we have $x,y\ge0$, we won't run into $y=-x/2$ except at the origin. And $z=2-x^{2}-y$ intersects $z=0$ when $y=2-x^{2}$, which makes a parabola in the $xy$-plane (as opposed to the vertical, parallel to the $xz$-plane, parabolas discussed above).

Now, it matters which side of the parabola $y=2-x^{2}$ has a piece of the volume. If $y>2-x^{2}$, then $z=2-x^{2}-y<0$, so that region is not part of the volume. It's only the region of the first quadrant of the $xy$-plane where $y\le2-x^{2}$ that matters.

Finally, above where in the $xy$-plane do the two complicated surfaces intersect? $z=2-x^{2}-y=x+2y$ means $y=\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$ (a different parabola). Again, it matters what happens on both sides of this parabola. If $y<\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$, then $x+2y$ decreases and $2-x^{2}-y$ increases, so that $z\le x+2y$ is the stronger condition. On the other hand, if $y>\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$, then $z\le2-x^{2}-y$ is the stronger condition.

#### Intersections of curves:

You might think we're done, especially if you've graphed things with a computer/calculator already. But we need to seriously consider what happens with these two parabolas in the $xy$-plane. It matters which one is outside the other, or if they intersect in the first quadrant. $y=\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$ and $y=2-x^{2}$ intersect at the points $\left(\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{33}}{4},\dfrac{-1\mp\sqrt{33}}{8}\right)$. One of those two points has a negative value for $x$, and the other has a negative value for $y$, so neither appears in the first quadrant. Thus, one parabola is outside the other in the first quadrant.

If $y=\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$ were the outside one, then the intersection of $z=x+2y$ and $z=2-x^{2}-y$ wouldn't matter; it would happen beyond the curve where $z=2-x^{2}-y$ dips below $z=0$. But actually, by considering some test ray like $x=y$, we see that $y=\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$ includes $\left(\sqrt{6}-2,\sqrt{6}-2\right)$ and $y=2-x^{2}$ includes $\left(1,1\right)$. So $y=2-x^{2}$ is the outer parabola.

### Picture and integrals:

#### Picture:

Putting all of the intersection information together, we arrive at a schematic of the first quadrant that looks like this:

[image: plot of the first quadrant with two downward parabolas. above y=2-x^2 is "N/A", between y=2-x^2 and y=(2-x-x^2)/3 is "2-x^2-y", and below y=(2-x-x^2)/3 is "x+2y"]

The region labeled "N/A" does not lie under the volume. The other two regions are for $2-x^{2}-y$ and $x+2y$ representing the height above the points in those regions.

#### Integrals:

We know the $y=2-x^{2}$ parabola intersects the axes at $(0,2)$ and $\left(\sqrt{2},0\right)$. In order to actually set up a sum of iterated integrals, we need to know (at least one of) the intersections of $y=\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$ with the axes as well. They are $\left(0,\frac{2}{3}\right)$ and $(1,0)$.

This leads naturally to a sum of three iterated integrals with $x$ on the outside:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}}x+2y\,\mathrm{d}y+\int_{\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}}^{{\displaystyle 2-x^{2}}}2-x^{2}-y\,\mathrm{d}y\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$+\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{{\displaystyle 2-x^{2}}}2-x^{2}-y\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$$

However, using the $\left(0,\frac{2}{3}\right)$ point and solving the parabola equations for $y$, we could also write:

$$\int_{0}^{2/3}\left(\int_{0}^{\left(-1+\sqrt{9-12y}\right)/2}x+2y\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\left(-1+\sqrt{9-12y}\right)/2}^{\sqrt{2-y}}2-x^{2}-y\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\,\mathrm{d}y$$
$$+\int_{2/3}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-y}}2-x^{2}-y\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

### Checking our answers:

We can use a computer to check our answers. For instance:

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 415 bytes

```
Print[{
Expand@Volume[ImplicitRegion[x>=0&&y>=0&&z>=0&&z<=2-x^2-y&&z<=x+2y,{x,y,z}]],
Integrate[Integrate[x+2y,{y,0,(2-x-x^2)/3}]+Integrate[2-x^2-y,{y,(2-x-x^2)/3,2-x^2}],{x,0,1}]+Integrate[Integrate[2-x^2-y,{y,0,2-x^2}],{x,1,Sqrt[2]}],
Expand[Integrate[Integrate[x+2y,{x,0,(-1+Sqrt[9-12y])/2}]+Integrate[2-x^2-y,{x,(-1+Sqrt[9-12y])/2,Sqrt[2-y]}],{y,0,2/3}]+Integrate[Integrate[2-x^2-y,{x,0,Sqrt[2-y]}],{y,2/3,2}]]
}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDLCoMwEEX3fogoTjCmq0It3XThrrTQTUghWLEBX5UUEsVvt0ZLH2I3w2S4596Z5FzekpxLEfO@P9SikLTdq4oX1925zB55QqO8ykQs5DFJRVlQtQ2xbeuxNlPdhASpC0F67JVHNLQKNDQdY2BFhUzSmsvB6d1NGg0YnAE1sOuvOuZ9FC9HI/qSwDjumPHHEPwQiyz@JgI43WtJCRue1nQk/b@dSXBQ4I3MGgVEM9cny0uqBeUrDGkTN60yu3HRCM85Ys4efrJjff8E)

The output is `{-17/60 + (16*Sqrt[2])/15, -17/60 + (16*Sqrt[2])/15, -17/60 + (16*Sqrt[2])/15}`, indicating that whether you use Mathematica's black box calculation of the volume, or either iterated integral setup, you always get $\dfrac{16\sqrt2}{15}-\dfrac{17}{60}$.

---

## Only using algebra:

From the definition of $V$ and how integration works, the volume we need to calculate is $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\max\left(0,\min\left(2-x^{2}-y,x+2y\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

We know this works because the "$\max(0$" part ensures $z\ge0$ and that we do not accidentally include negative signed volume for points where the $\min$ is negative.

### Resolving the min:

Now, we first need to resolve $\min\left(2-x^{2}-y,x+2y\right)$. The key will be to find the points where both expressions are equal, and then we can hopefully see which side of those points we're on. $2-x^{2}-y=x+2y$ simplifies by algebra to $y=\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$. If $y$ increases, then $x+2y$ increases and $2-x^{2}-y$ decreases, so that $2-x^{2}-y$ would be the $\min$. And analogously if $y$ were less than that. Therefore, $$\min\left(2-x^{2}-y,x+2y\right)=\begin{cases}
x+2y & \text{ if }y\le\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}\\
2-x^{2}-y & \text{ if }y\ge\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}
\end{cases}$$

This changes our integral into the following:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\max\left(0,\begin{cases}
x+2y & \text{ if }y\le\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}\\
2-x^{2}-y & \text{ if }y\ge\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}
\end{cases}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\begin{cases}
\max\left(0,x+2y\right) & \text{ if }y\le\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}\\
\max\left(0,2-x^{2}-y\right) & \text{ if }y\ge\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}
\end{cases}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\begin{cases}
\max\left(0,x+2y\right) & \text{ if }y\le\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}\\
\max\left(0,2-x^{2}-y\right) & \text{ if }y\ge\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}
\end{cases}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{{\displaystyle \max\left(0,\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}\right)}}\max\left(0,x+2y\right)\,\mathrm{d}y\right.$$

$$\left.+\int_{{\displaystyle \max\left(0,\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}\right)}}^{\infty}\max\left(0,2-x^{2}-y\right)\,\mathrm{d}y\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

### Resolving each max:

Now we need to resolve each $\max$.

#### The max in the bounds:

Let's start with the one in the bounds of the integrals. $\max\left(0,\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}\right)$ switches when the expressions are equal. $0=\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}\Rightarrow x^{2}+x-2=0$. And since $x^{2}+x-2=\left(x-1\right)\left(x+2\right)$, the $\max$ switches when $x=1$ or when $x=-2$. But since we know the outer integral only depends on positive values of $x$, we don't care about $x=-2$. When $0\le x\le1$, $\max\left(0,\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}\right)=\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$ and when $x\ge1$, $\max\left(0,\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}\right)=0$.

Therefore, our integral above can be written as three iterated integrals in the following way:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}}\max\left(0,x+2y\right)\,\mathrm{d}y+\int_{\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}}^{\infty}\max\left(0,2-x^{2}-y\right)\,\mathrm{d}y\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$+\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\max\left(0,2-x^{2}-y\right)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$$

#### The simplest max:

Next, let's examine $\max\left(0,x+2y\right)$. This switches when $y=-\dfrac{x}{2}$, but for positive $x$ (as we have $\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\mathrm{d}x$) that's a negative value, and $\int_{0}^{\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}}\cdots\mathrm{d}y$ doesn't allow $y$ to be negative. So a switch can't happen, and we can test any value. For instance, if $x=\frac{1}{2}<1$ and $y=\frac{1}{4}<\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$, then $x+2y$ is positive since it's the sum of two positive values (and it equals $1$). So for the purposes of our first iterated integral, $\max\left(0,x+2y\right)=x+2y$.

#### The final max:

Finally, let's examine $\max\left(0,2-x^{2}-y\right)$. This switches when $y=2-x^{2}$. For the second iterated integral, it matters how this compares to $\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$ when $x\in\left[0,1\right]$. Well, $2-x^{2}=\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$ when $x=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{33}}{4}$. The plus sign makes $x>1$ and the minus sign makes $x<0$, so by testing a point like $x=\frac{1}{2}$, we can be sure that $2-x^{2}>\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$ always when we're within the bounds of the second iterated integral. Then for the integrand, we can test a point like $x=\frac{1}{2}<1$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}>\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}$; then $2-x^{2}-y=\frac{5}{4}>0$. So $\max\left(0,2-x^{2}-y\right)=2-x^{2}-y$ until $y=2-x^{2}$. For the third iterated integral, $2-x^{2}\ge0$ for $x\ge1$ whenever $x\le\sqrt{2}$; for any larger $x$ with $y$ nonnegative, $2-x^{2}-y$ is clearly negative.

### The answer:

Putting this all together, we have the following:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}}x+2y\,\mathrm{d}y+\int_{\dfrac{2-x-x^{2}}{3}}^{{\displaystyle 2-x^{2}}}2-x^{2}-y\,\mathrm{d}y\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$+\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{{\displaystyle 2-x^{2}}}2-x^{2}-y\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$$